# Trouble adding Images into a Gui using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

OK so i am trying to make a program that displays an image when pressing a button, and i am having trouble getting the images into the program
this is my full code:

```
# Nicolas Bart
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Bad Meme Generator')
window.geometry('500x500')
window.configure(bg='saddle brown')

meme_label = tk.Label(window, text='PRESS BUTTON FOR BAD MEMES:', 
fg='blue4', bg='brown4', font=('comicsans', '20'))
meme_label.grid(pady=25, padx=25, column=0, row=0)


def button_command():
    meme_window = tk.Tk()
    meme_window.title('I Warned You')
    meme_window.grid()

image = Image.open('pexels-photo-247932.jpg')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


label = tk.Label(meme_window, image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.place(x = 0, y = 0)


button = tk.Button(window, text='Dont Do It!', command=button_command, 
padx=100, pady=75, font=('comicsans', '20'),
               bg='brown4', fg='blue4')
button.grid(column=0, row=1)

warning_label = tk.Label(window, text="Really shit tier memes incoming:", 
bg='brown4', fg='blue4',
                         font=('comicsans', '20'))
warning_label.grid(pady=75)

window.mainloop()
```

every time i run this program, when i press the button to open the image, it gives the error "AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'"

the specific part of the program that is giving the error is:

```
def button_command():
    meme_window = tk.Tk()
    meme_window.title('I Warned You')
    meme_window.grid()

    image = Image.open('pexels-photo-247932.jpg')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    label = tk.Label(meme_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.place(x = 0, y = 0)
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example of why you shouldn't do `from tkinter import *`. Tkinter has an `Image` class, so by doing this import after importing `Image` from PIL you overwrite the `PIL` class with the tkinter class.

Since you're already importing tkinter the preferred way (`import tkinter as tk`), you don't need to import tkinter a second time. You need to remove the statement `from tkinter import *`.

You also make the mistake of creating more than one instance of `Tk`. I don't know if it contributes to the problem or not, but it's not something you should be doing. If you need additional windows then you should create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the problem myself and it was because As you said, I used more than one instance of tk. I fixed the problem by using Toplevel.